# Security Exception in application hosted in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7, hosting

When i am getting an error while hosting an application in IIs 7.
The error says 
"the application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security Policy".

I have the same copy of the application hosted in the same machine.
That application is working fine but this one is not.

Any help.

Comment: Can you paste the full exception and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by accessing some shared resources in your code.
More info [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1192379.aspx/1?Application%20attempted%20to%20perform%20an%20operation%20not%20allowed%20by%20the%20security%20policy) and [here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493%28VS.80%29.aspx)

May be, the problem will be solved by adding

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
</system.web>
```

to the web.config.

You should check all your code for accessing shared resources - various applications can be runned under various accounts, and they can have different rights

Comment: I have found the same thing in some other sites also but before applying i wanted to know what it does and whats wrong in the hosting.